# In pandas expanding/rolling function, how to use the index of the a dataframe or series?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Let say I have a `pandas.Series` with a datetime index:

```
srs = pd.Series(index = pd.date_range('2013-01-01','2013-01-10' )).fillna(1)
```

I can use the `expanding` function to calculate say expanding sum of the series.

```
srs.expanding(5).sum()
```

However, I can not access other properties of the series (say its index) by using the expanding function. For example by running:

```
srs.expanding(5).apply(lambda x: x.index[-1])
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Why are the groups are passed as `numpy` array as opposed to `pandas.Series`? Is there another way to use expanding/rolling functions to have access to the indices as well?

Comment: i believe both expanding and rolling will pass the `.values` slice of whatever the index split is

Comment: You can test this by defining a function and print type of the argument that is passed.

Comment: `def f(x):`
`print(type(x),x)`
`return 0`

`srs.expanding(5).apply(f)`

Comment: Yep, only the np.array is passed, not the dataframe with indexes.

Comment: You can pass `raw=False` to `apply` (this is a parameter to indicate whether you want to pass the data as a numpy array or as a Series and valid in `groupby.apply` too). This will fail in your example because your lambda function doesn't return a number but I am assuming it was for illustration purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the indices by using the expanding, but if the indices have the same type as values.
For example it works:

```
s1 = pd.Series(index = range(10)).fillna(1)
s1.expanding(5).agg(lambda x: x.index[-1])
```

But it doesn't work:

```
srs = pd.Series(index = pd.date_range('2013-01-01','2013-01-10' )).fillna(1)
srs.expanding(5).agg(lambda x: x.index[-1])
```